# Making a Device Driver in Minix

Tags: c, driver, minix

I'm trying to create a character device driver on Minix.  I would like it to be able to accept `read()` and `write()` calls. My understanding is that I would need to use `sys_safecopyfrom()` for the function which runs the `read()` function and `sys_safecopyto()` for the function which runs the `write()` function.  The issue is that I keep getting a similar error (although not exactly the same, but I think that the differences are memory locations) when I run it like this.  The error is:

```
verify_grant: grant verify failed: access invalid: want 0x..., have 0x...
grant 2 verify to copy ... -> ... by ... failed err -1
read: Operation not permitted
```

The "..." are memory locations and the error is similar for write except for the memory locations and it says "write" instead of "read" on the last line.

I think that the relevant code is the following:

```
#include <minix/drivers.h>
#include <minix/chardriver.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <minix/ds.h>
...
static struct chardriver hello_tab =
{
    .cdr_open   = hello_open,
    .cdr_close  = hello_close,
    .cdr_read   = hello_read,
    .cdr_write  = hello_write,
};
...
static ssize_t hello_read(devminor_t UNUSED(minor), u64_t position,
    endpoint_t endpt, cp_grant_id_t grant, size_t size, int UNUSED(flags),
    cdev_id_t UNUSED(id))
{
    u64_t dev_size;
    char *ptr;
    int ret;
    char *buf = HELLO_MESSAGE;

    printf("hello_read()\n");

    /* This is the total size of our device. */
    dev_size = (u64_t) strlen(buf);

    /* Check for EOF, and possibly limit the read size. */
    if (position >= dev_size) return 0;     /* EOF */
    if (position + size > dev_size)
        size = (size_t)(dev_size - position);   /* limit size */

    /* Copy the requested part to the caller. */
    ptr = buf + (size_t)position;
    if ((ret = sys_safecopyfrom(endpt, grant, 0, (vir_bytes) ptr, size)) != OK)
        return ret;

    /* Return the number of bytes read. */
    printf("Message is :%s", ptr);
    return size;
}
static ssize_t hello_write(devminor_t UNUSED(minor), u64_t position,
    endpoint_t endpt, cp_grant_id_t grant, size_t size, int UNUSED(flags),
    cdev_id_t UNUSED(id))
{
    u64_t dev_size;
    char *ptr;
    int ret;
    char *buf = HELLO_MESSAGE;

    printf("hello_write()\n");

    /* This is the total size of our device. */
    dev_size = (u64_t) strlen(buf);

    /* Check for EOF, and possibly limit the read size. */
    if (position >= dev_size) return 0;     /* EOF */
    if (position + size > dev_size)
        size = (size_t)(dev_size - position);   /* limit size */

    /* Copy the requested part to the caller. */
    ptr = buf + (size_t)position;
    if ((ret = sys_safecopyto(endpt, grant, 0, (vir_bytes) ptr, size)) != OK)
        return ret;

    /* Return the number of bytes read. */
    return size;
}
```

The hello_read function is based off of the hello_write functions but I think that it should still work and should read the information into ptr.

Also, I'm a bit hazy on how I would go about getting the second argument in the `write()` function (the buffer) in my `hello_write()` function.  Is it contained in one of `hello_read()`'s arguments?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So, I know it's been a long time and there's no activity here but I thought I would answer the question.

I am going to start by saying the the error occurs when passing the wrong arguments into sys_safecopyto/from.

Now to really debug this I would want to see the rest of the code you had. But for anyone else who comes across this problem I'm going to give some tips

- look at how many bytes you are passing the the sys_safecopy funcitons
- make sure you are putting the correct offset with the buffer when writing.  For 
  the case I used it in that was (buffer_ptr + current_size)
- make sure if you are using an earlier version of minix that you are putting in the correct amount of parameters into the sys_safecopy funcitons (could be 5 args or 6 args, the last one on older versions of minix for the hello driver would just be "D" ;) )